# Unknown column 'conversations_members' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql-error-1054

Hi I'm following a tutorial and struggling, as I'm up to a point where I've got the message:

```
Unknown column 'conversations_members' in 'where clause'
```

I've searched and looked and just cant work out how to solve the situation.

Here are the three tables I have:

**conversations**

```
conversation_id | conversation_subject
```

**conversations_members**

```
conversation_id | user_id | conversation_last_view | conversation_deleted
```

**conversations_messages**

```
message_id | conversation_id | user_id | message_date | message_text
```

Here is the the query that's causing the problem for me.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        `conversations`.`conversation_id`,
        `conversations`.`conversation_subject`,
        MAX(`conversations_messages`.`message_date`) AS `conversation_last_reply`
    FROM `conversations`
    LEFT JOIN `conversations_messages` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_messages`.`conversation_id`
    INNER JOIN `conversations_members` ON `conversations`.`conversation_id` = `conversations_members`.`conversation_id`
    WHERE `conversations_members`= `{$_SESSION['user_id']}`
    AND `conversations_members`.`conversation_deleted` = 0
    GROUP BY `conversations`.`conversation_id`
    ORDER BY `conversation_last_reply` DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$conversations = array();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {
    $conversations[] = array(
        'id'         => $row['conversation_id'],
        'subject'    => $row['conversation_subject'],
        'last_reply' => $row['conversation_last_reply']
    );
}

return $conversations;
```

I have a `die(mysql_error());` to pick up the error before I carried on the function, if you require the complete functions code I can provide it.

Can someone help and explain where I have gone wrong and why?

Cheers

..ps what would u suggest?

Answer (score 2):

The error is in this line:

```
WHERE `conversations_members`= `{$_SESSION['user_id']}`
```

Basically, the error says exactly what it means - it expects a condition on columns in `WHERE` clause and there is no column named `conversations_members`. Hence, the error. You probably want `user_id` column of `conversations_members` table instead, judging by the `$_SESSION['user_id']`.

```
WHERE `conversations_members`.`user_id`= `{$_SESSION['user_id']}`
```

Comment: I'm trying that now, I really considered it so many times but didn't cause he tutorial didn't have it so I thought it be pointless

Comment: i edited the code and now i get " mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource... the line it refers to is ..."while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false) {" .. but the rest of the code  for the function is amended above

Comment: 1. change !== to !=. 2. Can you run your query outside PHP to check if it works? Usually that error is because of query error...

Comment: 3. Do you have a proper DB connection somewhere before these things?

Comment: This is a different error though - if you can't figure it out post another question, this answer fixes the initial problem so should be accepted. It is not a good practice adding stuff and expanding your question as you go...

Comment: I firstly tested the query in SQL thing on phpmyadmin and it ran fine, .. I tried the rest of the function with !== and != and the warning is still the same.. "Warning : mysql_fetch_assoc: supplied argument is not a valid resource

Comment: Did you do mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");?

Comment: i put in a mysql_error to check whats happening and it goes back to the original problem this time tho, as we have added the .user_id in the query, it comes out "Unknown column '2' in 'where clause'" any ideas?

Comment: think i have fixed it now, all that is shown is Array(). cheers for the help!